# Unable to generate TFrecords for train module

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am following the instructions in this github page:https://github.com/EdjeElectronics/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-API-Tutorial-Train-Multiple-Objects-Windows-10#1-install-anaconda-cuda-and-cudnn and everything went fine till generating the record files for the test module but I got all these errors for the  [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1a0Bs.png) training module:

This is the error I am getting...can anyone pls help me?

(PS: This is my first time asking a question on StackOverflow)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the file test_labels.csv, maybe one of the cells is empty. How did you create the label files, using a labeling tool?

Comment: Yeah, I used the"LabelImg" tool to label the images. There are no empty cells but I do have a doubt. In the folder called train, I have about 40 images but have only labeled 12 images and converted them into .xml files. And then I converted them into a .csv file. So should I remove the unlabeled images

Comment: I think that shouldn't be a problem, since the generate_tfrecords script reads the files whose names are in the csv file. Try checking the label file (and comparing it to the csv file), maybe you've misspelled a name of the class somewhere. Check the classes for None types in the csv file also.

Comment: Thank you so much. As you said i had misspelled a class name. Success